# Concat nested field values if they exist

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am working on concatenating the values of nested fields but not able to succeed with aggregations

I have written code to concat the 5 nested fields that are in my DB

The address field in a collection named 'level' is as follows

```
"address":{
    "flatNo" : "101",
    "street" : "amprapali",
    "city" : "jaipur",
    "zip" : "123456",
    "state" : "rajasthan",
    "country" : "INDIA"
}
```

What output I want

```
"address":"#101, amprapali, jaipur, 123456, rajasthan, INDIA"
```

My code:

```
aggregation_pipeline = [ 
    {
        "$project":
        {
            "address": { "$concat": [ "#", "$address.flatNo", ", ", "$address.street", ", ", "$address.city", ", ", "$address.zip", ", ", "$address.state", ", ", "$address.country" ] }
        }


    },
    {
        "$out": "mod_collection"
    }
]
cursor = db['level'].aggregate(aggregation_pipeline, allowDiskUse=True)
cursor.close()
```

I am getting this expected result but if any of the 5 fields are not present in source db the address field is getting populated with `null`

My requirement is to concat all existing field values of address fields separated by ','

How can I omit the `null` values when not all fields under address exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options here depending on your MongoDB version:

For releases 3.4.4 and above, use [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and select the fields dynamically:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
     "address": {
       "$let": {
         "vars": { 
           "address": { 
             "$reduce": {
               "input": { "$objectToArray": "$address" },
               "initialValue": "",
               "in": { "$concat": [ "$$value", "$$this.v", ", " ] }
             }
           }
         },
         "in": {
           "$concat": [ "#", 
             { "$substrCP": [
               "$$address",
               0,
               { "$subtract": [{ "$strLenCP": "$$address" }, 2] }
             ]}
           ]
         }
       }
     }
  }},
  { "$out": "newcollection" }
])
```

For 3.4 prior to the minor release, use a [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to remove the `null` values

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
     "address": {
       "$let": {
         "vars": { 
           "address": { 
             "$reduce": {
               "input": { 
                 "$filter": {
                   "input": [
                     "$address.flatNo", "$address.street", "$address.city",
                     "$address.zip","$address.state","$address.country"
                   ],
                   "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$this", null ] }
                 }
               },
               "initialValue": "",
               "in": { "$concat": [ "$$value", "$$this", ", " ] }
             }
           }
         },
         "in": {
           "$concat": [ "#", 
             { "$substrCP": [
               "$$address",
               0,
               { "$subtract": [{ "$strLenCP": "$$address" }, 2] }
             ]}
           ]
         }
       }
     }
  }},
  { "$out": "newcollection" }
])
```

Prior to 3.4 you don't have [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) or [`$strLenCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/), which enables the "joining" in a dynamic way. So you probably want to do this in code instead:

```
var batch = [];

db.collection.find({}, { _id: 0, address: 1 }).forEach(doc => {

   doc.address =  "#" + Object.keys(doc.address).map(k => doc.address[k]).join( ", ");
   batch.push(doc);

   if ( batch.length >= 1000 ) {
     db.newcollection.insertMany(batch);
     batch = [];
   }
})

if ( batch.length > 0 ) {
  db.newcollection.insertMany(batch);
   batch = [];
}
```

Or really long winded with [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) and [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "address": {
      "$concat": [
        "#",
        { "$ifNull": [ "$address.flatNo", ""] },
        { "$cond": [{ "$ifNull": [ "$address.flatNo", false ] }, ", ", ""] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$address.street", "" ] },
        { "$cond": [{ "$ifNull": [ "$address.street", false ] }, ", ", ""] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$address.city", "" ] },
        { "$cond": [{ "$ifNull": [ "$address.city", false ] }, ", ", ""] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$address.zip", "" ] },
        { "$cond": [{ "$ifNull": [ "$address.zip", false ] }, ", ", ""] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$address.state", "" ] },
        { "$cond": [{ "$ifNull": [ "$address.state", false ] }, ", ", ""] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$address.country", "" ] }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

The code approach would be cleaner, but if you are writing to another collection then the [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) with [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) at least allows the usage of [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) to avoid bringing all documents back "over the wire" before writing them back again.

Comment: I use MongoDB 4.0 and your answer for 3.4.4 and above versions did work to a great extent to meet my requirements. Thank you!!

Comment: My apologies. I am new to this site and this was the first question I posted. I have accepted the answer as you said and going forward will follow the conventions of the site. Thanks.